# lazy listview with many textviews and spinner

Tags: android, listview, android-lazyadapter

Hi I am developing an android SMS app where in I am trying to include settings.xml similar to the below image.But not sure of how to include these on a listview using a lazy adapter.

Please suggest.Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Either use an ExpandableListView or override getView of custom Adapter to fill the data this way

Comment: for that you should go with Preferences...